# Change Listitem background color

Tags: java, android, android-listview

i am creating a list of added subjects in my timetable and how can i change the background color of list item to red if the subject status is equal to closed .

```
        for (DataTimetable cn : timetable) {

        String section = cn.getSection();
        String subjects = cn.getSubject();
        String day = cn.getDay();
        String timein = cn.getTimeIn();
        String timeout = cn.getTimeOut();
        String room = cn.getRoom();
        String units = cn.getUnits();
                    String status = cn.getStatus();

        total = total + Double.parseDouble(units);

        String time = timein + " - " + timeout;

        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(TAG_SECTION, section);
        map.put(TAG_SUBJECT, subjects);
        map.put(TAG_DAY, day);
        map.put(TAG_TIME, time);
        map.put(TAG_ROOM, room);
        map.put(TAG_UNITS, units);
        map.put(TAG_STATUS, status);

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        TimetableList.add(map);

    }
```

Comment: Do you have a ArrayAdapter? Pls have a look at these tutorials http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: yes. but i just want to know that how can i change the background color of listitem if the subject status is equal to close without selecting

Comment: see my answer, i do net get what your problem is

Comment: so please post your ArrayAdapter

Answer (score 0):

In your getView(...) in your ArrayAdapter use this.

```
if(YOUR_CONDITION){
  convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);   
}else{
  convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
}
```

Comment: can you give me a full sample of getView and how can i use that in my codes

Comment: plaese have a look at this tut Point 10 http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html